# HTML input + label collides with JSSOR gallery's script - ANY FIX?

Tags: html, css, image, jssor

I wonder if anyone tried to add `input radio buttons` and associated `labels` into JSSOR image gallery. This is the prototype I tried to achieve and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/agq0rgoL/

The goal is to set the very first `input` and `label` as default by having it `checked` until you click the next `label`(I put `img` inside the label) which will link to its associated radio button. In the end I used `input:checked` and `input:checked + label` to modify their styles (opacity in this case)

But this linkage between radio button and label does not work when you insert them into to JSSOR gallery. `checked` is not working as well.

Just like to know if there is a workaround/fix for this.

Comment: This bug had been fixed, please download the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been fixed, please download the latest version.

Also, please remove the `<A>` element from your html code.

That's to say replace,

```
<a><img src="http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/thumbnail1.jpg"></a>
```

with

```
<img src="http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/thumbnail1.jpg">
```

Comment: did you fix this problem recently? is there a post/article regarding this issue?

Comment: I just download the master pack and it works. thank you